# Changing a value inside an array of bits

Tags: c, arrays, byte, bit

I have a "bitmap" lets say, 64 wide. Meaning 8 bits per Byte. `0000 0000` and let's say I want to activate the second bit, `0100 0000`.

I tried making an array of unsigned char and using memcpy.

```
memcpy(bitmap[2], 1, sizeof(1));
```

I even tried declaring 1 in a unsigned char variable.

```
unsigned char bit = 1;
memcpy(bitmap[2], bit, sizeof(bit));
```

I know that strcpy wont solve anything in this case and memcpy isn't solving it either apparently, there is a proper way to do this for sure. I'm no C expert as you can see..

Maybe I shouldn't be trying to change the value inside the array like this?

Comment: `"bitmap" lets say, 64 wide` - 64 *bits* wide? So 8 bytes? Is that a single `long` or an array of 8 chars?

Comment: @Mike Yes 8 bytes, I wont be using it as a byte for now, only want to be able to tell the position I want to change and have it change the bitmap for me. The bitmap will be array of unsigned chars, if I shouldn't do it like this please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume that your bitmap looks like that

```
unsigned char bitmap[8] = {0};
```

and you want to activate the second bit (from the left) of the first byte in your `bitmap` array (`bitmap[0]`):

```
bitmap[0] = 1U<<6;
```

the `bitmap[0]` binary presentation will be `0100 0000`

**EDIT**

`bitmap[i]` is 8 bits size.

```
bitmap[0] = 1<<6; // means 1 shifted to the left with 6 steps


                                  1<<0
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1

                            1<<1
0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0

                       1<<2
0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0

                  1<<3
0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0

......

   1<<6
0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me how this works, I don't want to just throw it on the code, I want to learn it too. I'm assuming it will insert the '1' six houses from right to left?

Comment: Yes, I had, sorry. I was moving them into the wrong position and the Hex values weren't right, as I wasn't hardcoding the positions. The code works, thanks for your help.